# After adding a function using OpenSSL my code no longer outputs anything

Tags: c++, openssl, sha256

I'm trying to make a simple function that generates the sha256 hash of a string and truncates said hash at 16 bytes, so I installed OpenSSL, the installation seems to be working fine since I can access the constants inside the library like `EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE` which is equal to 64. This is the code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstddef>
#include "xtensor.hpp"
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include "openssl/sha.h"
#include "openssl/evp.h"

// There are a bunch of other functions here, these all work fine and have been tested beforehand

std::string hash_string(const std::string& unhashed)
{
    std::string hashed = "";
    EVP_MD_CTX* context = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(context, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(context, unhashed.c_str(), unhashed.length());
    unsigned char hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int lengthOfHash = 0;
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(context, hash, &lengthOfHash);
    std::stringstream ss;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < lengthOfHash; ++i)
        {
            ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)hash[i];
        }
    hashed = ss.str();
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(context);
    return hashed;
}


int main(){
    std::string input = "Hello, world!";
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    printf("a");
    std::string output = hash_string(input);
    std::cout << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There are a bunch of extra `#include` at the top, those are for other functions inside my code, those functions all work fine, I've tested them before adding the new `hash_string` function.

My error is quite simple, the code simply returns nothing, it runs and returns nothing, not even the
`input` string which should be printed before the `hash_string` function is even called.

The first thing I tried is commenting out the `hash_string` function (I comment out the function but keep the `#include "openssl/evp.h"` at the top). If I do this the code runs and outputs just fine:

```
int main(){
    std::string input = "Hello, world!";
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    printf("a");
    //std::string output = hash_string(input);
    //std::cout << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the output becomes:

```
Hello, world!
a
```

Next, I tried to add a `return hashed` line into the `hash_string` function, starting at the first line and going down, and the error of no output happened again (without calling the function in any way) when it looked like this:

```
std::string hash_string(const std::string& unhashed)
{
    std::string hashed = "";
    EVP_MD_CTX* context = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    return hashed;
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(context, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(context, unhashed.c_str(), unhashed.length());
    unsigned char hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int lengthOfHash = 0;
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(context, hash, &lengthOfHash);
    std::stringstream ss;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < lengthOfHash; ++i)
        {
            ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)hash[i];
        }
    hashed = ss.str();
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(context);
    return hashed;
}

int main(){
    std::string input = "Hello, world!";
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    printf("a");
    //std::string output = hash_string(input);
    //std::cout << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So, as you can see, the `hash_string` function isn't being called in any way but simply having it there somehow makes it so even simple commands like `printf("a")` don't print anything to the console.

In response to a comment I recieved I will expand on how I'm running the code: I'm using Visual Studio Code and the Code Runner Extension, I'm using Mingw as the compiler and the command used to run the code is the following: `cd $dir && g++ -I \"C:/Users/Batres/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include\" -L \"C:/Users/Batres/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib\" $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt -lssl -lcrypto && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"`. As you can see, the libraries I'm making use of, `XTensor` and `OpenSSL` have been installed using `vcpkg` and both are the `x64-windows` version. Aside from this I also tried stripping everything else in the file and was left with the following, while still maintaning the error I mentioned:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "openssl/evp.h"

std::string hash_string(const std::string& unhashed)
{
    std::string hashed = "";
    EVP_MD_CTX* context = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(context, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(context, unhashed.c_str(), unhashed.length());
    unsigned char hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int lengthOfHash = 0;
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(context, hash, &lengthOfHash);
    std::stringstream ss;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < lengthOfHash; ++i)
        {
            ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)hash[i];
        }
    hashed = ss.str();
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(context);
    return hashed;
}


int main(){
    std::string input = "Hello, world!";
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    printf("a");
    //std::string output = hash_string(input);
    return 0;
}
```

This code, again, return nothing at all, no errors, nothing.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Taking the alleged problematic code fragment, almost a [mre], and needed only removal of the local header file and addition of `<iostream>`, the resulting code compiles without errors, runs, and produces the expected output: "Hello world", followed by a hash. You can try this yourself, and see for yourself. No errors reported by valgrind. There are no obvious issues with the shown code, so if you have any issues it must be with code that's not shown, and nobody will be able to help you with that, obviously.

Comment: I updated the post with some extra information, which may explain the discrepancy in your version working and mine not.

Comment: You updated the question and added another code examples. The new code example compiles without any errors, and runs fine. The only output is "a" because everything else is commented out. Uncommenting the call to `hash_string`, and adding `std::cout << output << std::endl;` results in the expected output, without any errors. Unable to reproduce your problem, and there's nothing wrong with the shown code.